# How to filter symmetric words from a column of data?

Tags: excel

I have a list of words and I would like to find all symmetric words and some how put value 1 for each of them (see the picture).

[image]

Comment: Would **ABBA** be symmetric?

Comment: @ Gary's student: Yes, it is!

Comment: `=A1=Reverse(A1)`? https://superuser.com/q/121618/52365

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick:

```
=1*(A1=CONCAT(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1),0),1)))
```

It reads the string in a cell backwards using `MID` and `SEQUENCE`, and compares the `CONCAT` result with the original to see if it is the same, i.e. the string is symmetric.

Multiplying by `1` forces the Boolean into an integer.

[image: symmetric]

Comment: Yup, that's nice and clean

Comment: Cool! .......................wish I could upvote more than once.

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft365, try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=EXACT(A1,CONCAT(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1),,LEN(A1),-1),1)))
```

Formula in `C1`:

```
=--EXACT(A1,CONCAT(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1),,LEN(A1),-1),1)))
```

---

If you are working in a version without `CONCAT()` it will get significatly more verbose, but still possible:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT(MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),MID(A1,(LEN(A1)+1)-ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)))=LEN(A1)
```

This, again, can be wrapped to return either `1` or `0` if you prefer that over the boolean results:

```
=--(=SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT(MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),MID(A1,(LEN(A1)+1)-ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)))=LEN(A1))
```

Answer (score 1):

With VBA.  This assumes that a single character is symmetric:

```
Public Function Sym(s As String) As Long
    Dim L As Long, L2 As Long
    Dim p1 As String, p2 As String
    
    L = Len(s)
    L2 = Int(L / 2)
    Sym = 0
    
    If L Mod 2 = 0 Then
    '   even
        p1 = Mid(s, 1, L2)
        p2 = StrReverse(Mid(s, L2 + 1))
        If p1 = p2 Then
            Sym = 1
        End If
    Else
    '   odd
        p1 = Mid(s, 1, L2)
        p2 = StrReverse(Mid(s, L2 + 2))
        If p1 = p2 Then
            Sym = 1
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

This will handle both an even or odd number of characters.

**EDIT#1:**

Simply:

```
Public Function Sym(s As String) As Long
    Sym = 0
    If s = StrReverse(s) Then Sym = 1
End
```

Comment: How does one assume a single character **isn't** symmetric?

Comment: @JMP  Well you gotta assume something!

Comment: @JMP  Glad you asked the question.....see my **EDIT#1**